# scipy.optimize.lsq_linear bounds error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, tuples

I am trying to jsut the following formula:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html#scipy.optimize.lsq_linear

I have the following code but it will not accept the bounds for 6 seperate variables it will only accept one tuple which makes the bounds the same for all variables.

```
## cut benchmark out of data
benchmark_ser = data_df.ix[:,0]
##  get out the stocks data
stocks_df = data_df.ix[:,1:]

## create/get bounds
bds = (0,.2) # <- i want to change this line 
             #    to something that will provide 
             #    a bound for each variable like 
             #    [(0,.1),(0,.2),(0,.5),(0,.6)]

wgt_arr = sp.optimize.lsq_linear(stocks_df, benchmark_ser, bds)
```

I get the following error currently:

```
ValueError: 'bounds' must contain 2 elements.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html#scipy.optimize.lsq_linear) (emphasis mine):

> bounds : 2-tuple of array_like, optional
>
> Lower and upper bounds on independent variables. Defaults to no bounds. **Each array must have shape (n,) or be a scalar**, in the latter case a bound will be the same for all variables. Use `np.inf` with an appropriate sign to disable bounds on all or some variables.

So, rather than giving it a list of `(lower_bound, upper_bound)` tuples, you need a tuple of two array-like objects: (1) all the lower bounds and (2) all the upper bounds

Try changing from

```
bds = [(0,.1),(0,.2),(0,.5),(0,.6)]
```

to

```
bds = ([0., 0., 0., 0.], [.1, .2, .5, .6])
```